# Is splitting DTOs per HTTP request an antipattern?

Tags: c#, api, rest

1. Let's say I have an API controller that handles some basic CRUD operations. You can post `BookDto` to it, return a collection of `BookDto` from it, etc. However, some of the fields that are necessary in the output are not utilized when posting (eg. `Id`). Is it okay to split the `BookDto` into `PostBookDto` and `GetBookDto`? Does not splitting them violate the [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)?
2. If I split the `BookDto` into `PostBookDto` and `GetBookDto`, some of their properties will be duplicated on both DTOs. Is it okay to keep it like that or does that violate the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle? Should the common part of those two DTOs be extracted into a base `BookDto` class then?

Comment: my advice is you also investigate GraphQL if you haven't done so, maybe that is something you want instead of a lot of different dto's.

Comment: Thanks, AFAIK GraphQL solves the issues with API being too 'talkative' by default with the way it works. However, I'm looking to solve those issues without switching from REST.